# error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'cdkDropList'

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I had problem installing cdk but I figured it out. However I still get those errors. How to fix them?

Error: src/app/subPages/home-boards/home-boards.component.html:15:18 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'cdkDropList'.

15       #todoList="cdkDropList"
~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/subPages/home-boards/home-boards.component.ts:8:16
8   templateUrl: './home-boards.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component HomeBoardsComponent.

Error: src/app/subPages/home-boards/home-boards.component.html:16:7 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'cdkDropListData' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

16       [cdkDropListData]="todo"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/subPages/home-boards/home-boards.component.ts:8:16
8   templateUrl: './home-boards.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component HomeBoardsComponent.

× Failed to compile.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { LogInComponent } from './subPages/log-in/log-in.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './subPages/home-page/home-page.component';

import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RegisterComponent } from './subPages/register/register.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthComponent } from './APIs/auth/auth.component';
import { GetDataComponent } from './APIs/get-data/get-data.component';
import { BoardsComponent } from './APIs/boards/boards.component'

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl, FormBuilder, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import {ToastrService, ToastrModule} from 'ngx-toastr'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LogInComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    GetDataComponent,
    BoardsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DragDropModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({

    }),
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
    // RouterModule.forRoot([
    //   {
    //     path: '',
    //     component: HomePageComponent,
    //   },
    //   {
    //     path: 'log-in',
    //     component: LogInComponent
    //   },
    //   {
    //     path: 'register',
    //     component: RegisterComponent
    //   }
    // ])
  ]
  ,
  providers: [AuthComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

div class="board_columns">

```
  <div class="board_column"
  cdkDropList
  #todoList="cdkDropList"
  [cdkDropListData]="todo"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="column-title">
      Todo
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you import `DragDropModule`? See the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api)

Comment: Yes. Sorry Ive posted wrong code. Now its correct. I imported this, though I had some issues with compatibility but now it doesnt have any errors.

Comment: I assume that's the html of the `BoardsComponent`?

Comment: Perhaps you can doublecheck if your `BoardsComponent` is only declared in one module. Also do you really need the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`? As a last resort, [here's](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/additional-samples/drag-drop) a working demo with [code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/additional-samples/drag-drop)

Comment: Damn. I checked it and it was home-boards Component which I didnt imported because i mixed it with BoardsComponent. Thank you for the clue, it works now!